# if json attribute value is duplicate, compare its another number property and set attribute biggerDuplicate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, duplicates

I have this code, where I am checking for duplicates, it has isDuplicate boolean if it is duplicate, but I want to extend my code and compare another property, which is number and set isBigger property, for the bigger one :)
Do you have some suggestions?
thank you so much

here is my code:

```
$scope.verifyDuplicate = function() {
  var names = [{
    "order": 1,
    "name": "a",
    "shortName": "a",
    "isDuplicate": false,
    "categoryId": 15070,
    "colorId": 50
  }, {
    "order": 2,
    "name": "s",
    "shortName": "s",
    "categoryId": 15071,
    "colorId": 51
  }, {
    "order": 3,
    "name": "h",
    "shortName": "g",
    "focused": 1513262627570,
    "isDuplicate": true,
    "categoryId": 15074,
    "colorId": 54
  }, {
    "order": 4,
    "name": "h",
    "shortName": "h",
    "isDuplicate": true,
    "categoryId": 15075,
    "colorId": 59
  }];
  var sorted, i;

  sorted = names.concat().sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.name > b.name)
      return 1;
    if (a.name < b.name)
      return -1;
    return 0;
  });
  for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if (sorted[i].name !== '') {
      sorted[i].isDuplicate = ((sorted[i - 1] && sorted[i - 1].name === sorted[i].name)) || ((sorted[i + 1] && sorted[i + 1].name === sorted[i].name));
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by adding your number as part of the sort. I assume it is `colorID`

Then create a temporary object that is a `groupBy` where `name` is used as keys and values are rrays of objects with that name.

Then loop through each of these groups and set your properties

```js
let sorted = names.sort(function(a, b) {
  // if names are same sort by colorId
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) || a.colorId > b.colorId
});

let tmp = sorted.reduce(function(a, c) {
  a[c.name] = a[c.name] || [];
  a[c.name].push(c);
  return a;
}, {});

Object.values(tmp).forEach(function(arr) {
  let len = arr.length,
    isDuplicate = len > 1;// if more than one in group they are all duplicates
  arr.forEach(function(o, i) {
    o.isDuplicate = isDuplicate;
    if (isDuplicate) {
      o.isBigger = i === len - 1;// already sorted by colorId so last one is biggest
    }
  });
});
console.log(sorted)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;}
```

```html
<script>
var names = [{
    "order": 1,
    "name": "a",
    "shortName": "a",    
    "categoryId": 15070,
    "colorId": 50
  }, {
    "order": 2,
    "name": "s",
    "shortName": "s",
    "categoryId": 15071,
    "colorId": 51
  }, {
    "order": 3,
    "name": "h",
    "shortName": "g",
    "focused": 1513262627570,   
    "categoryId": 15074,
    "colorId": 54
  }, {
    "order": 4,
    "name": "h",
    "shortName": "h",
    
    "categoryId": 15075,
    "colorId": 59
  }];
</script>
```

Comment: Charlietfl: thank you, but Object.values is not working on IE :/

Comment: can use a `for in` loop instead, or search for a polyfill